# Can I use my own https://<url> pointing to my cluster's ingress subdomain?

Tags: nginx, ibm-cloud, nginx-reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-config

Let me quickly explain this. 
I have one cluster on which xyz app is running and exposed in ingress URL. say `httpsprotocol://xyz.com`

I'm using IBM cloud.

Can I configured my own url say `httpsprotocol://myurl.com` pointing to the ingress subdomain URL.`httpsprotocol://xyz.com` How can I do that?

So every time when I hit myURL it should routes to ingresssubURL.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible. For https on your custom domain, you would need a TLS certificate. There is a [IBM Cloud solution tutorial which has optional steps to set up your own domain for ingress access](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/cloud-e2e-security.html#optional-use-a-custom-domain-and-encrypt-network-traffic). It has the source code and configuration files you could look at and adapt for your case.

There is also this blog post in which I show how to configure the URL and apply the certificate. Both the tutorial and the blog have links to the [IBM Cloud documentation for the basics](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_ingress.html#ingress_expose_public).